# How to count the number of characters entered in a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, io

I have a function that reads in a line from stdin and then returns the number of characters that the user inputted. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to count the number of characters. Here is the code:

```
 int  inputline(char* buf, size_t bufSize)
{
    static int numRead = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    //static int totalChars = 0;
    while (numRead < bufSize - 1 && ch != '\n') {
        ch = getchar();
        if(ch == EOF){
            if(feof(stdin)){
                ch = '\n'; //treated as if the user hit return and ends loop
                puts("EOF");
            }else{
                numRead = -1;
                break; //ends loop
            }
        }else{
            buf[numRead] = ch;
            ++numRead;

    }

    if (ch == '\n') {
        buf[numRead-1] = 0; // replace newline with null terminator
    } else {
        buf[bufSize-1] = 0; // ensure buffer is properly null terminated
    }

    while (ch != '\n') {
        ch = getchar();
    }

    return sizeof(buf);
}
}
```

I had thought `numRead` would count this but it doesn't and I'm not entirely sure why. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: If you use `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of the *pointer*, I think you're looking for [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: Oh, and if there's an error reading, you will most likely have garbage in your buffer.

Comment: 'strlen' seems to return an incorrect value though.

Comment: Then you're not setting the string terminator correctly. Run in a debugger, step through the code line by line, watch the values of all variables and the buffer. Oh, and are you sure you want `numRead` to be static? That means that each call to `inputline` will *append* to the buffer you provide, as long as `numRead` is small enough that is. You don't have any way to reset it.

Comment: Looks like there's some misleading indentation in the first `while` loop - the end brace that *looks* like it ends the `while` actually only ends the `else` for the `if(ch == EOF)`. Presumably that's why there's two braces at the end of the function.

Comment: Ok the bracket problem solved this...mostly. I am calling this function twice in my program the second time does not return the correct count. I'm sorry I'm really new to C.

Comment: @Steve314 Nevermind I forgot to clear something else out. It works now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are making your function a lot more complex than it needs to be. Here's a simplified version:

```
int inputline(char* buf, size_t bufSize)
{
   // Why did you have it static. It makes sense to be automatic.
   int numRead = 0;
   int ch = 0;

   // The logic to check for when to stop is much simpler
   while ( numRead < bufSize && ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') )
   {
      buf[numRead] = ch;
      ++numRead;
   }

   // Always null terminate the buffer.
   buf[numRead] = '\0';

   // You know how many characters were stored in buf.
   // Return it.
   return numRead;
}
```

Comment: I need to check for other input errors and return -1 if they are found.

Comment: @Rostro, you can add `&& !ferror(stdin)` to the list of checks in the `while` statement.